# How can I display time series graph with its forecasting line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The object is gettig parameters from users to make them understand the forecasting techniques. Therefore, i would like to begin with moving average. Eventhough the work is quite simple, i couldnt manage and i have some issues.

1. One error occurs: ERROR: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

I do not understand why do I get this?

2. I want to show forecasted values for next period. But with this ready formula does not provide that?

`

```
library(shiny)

    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Forecasting Methods"),
     sidebarPanel(

      h3(strong("Moving Average",style = "color:black")),
      br(),
      sliderInput("ord","Order Size:",min = 1, max = 100, step= 1, value = 15),

    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "ma1", width  = "700px",height = "400px"))

      ))

   library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(forecast)
    library(TTR)

      shinyServer(function(input, output){


           output$ma1 <- renderPlot( 
           tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:100, sales = round(runif(100, 150, 879))),
           sm <- SMA(tmp[,"sales"],order=input$ord),
           y <-ggplot(tmp, aes(time, sales)) + geom_line() + geom_line(aes(time,sm),color="red") + xlab("Days") + ylab("Sales Quantity")+ ggtitle("Moving Average"),
            y

              )


})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(TTR)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(    
  headerPanel("Forecasting Methods"),
  sidebarPanel(

    h3(strong("Moving Average",style = "color:black")),
    br(),
    sliderInput("ord","Order Size:",min = 1, max = 100, step= 1, value = 15)

  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "ma1", width  = "700px",height = "400px"))
)

server <- function(input, output){

  n <- 0
  output$ma1 <- renderPlot({ 
    input$ord
    tmp <- data.frame(time = 1:100, sales = round(runif(100, 150, 879)) )
    sm <- SMA(tmp[,"sales"],order=input$ord)
    title <- sprintf("Moving Average (%d)",n)
    n <<- n+1
    y <-ggplot(tmp, aes(time, sales)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      geom_line(aes(time,sm),color="red") + 
      xlab("Days") + ylab("Sales Quantity")+ ggtitle(title)
    y
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Yielding:

[image]

As to your program - I could not reproduce your errors exactly:

1 - the program as posted would not run. The server function code block was not enclosed in curly brackets (`{}`), but was structured like the ui function code (comma separated statements). This is wrong. The ui function code not a function like the server code, rather it series of function calls that output html/css/javascript. Try them from the R-console to see what I mean.

2 - the UI function had at least one extraneous comma that I had to get rid of in order for it to work.

3 - using `input$ord` in the `output$ma1` code that initializes the `sm` dataframe was not enough to cause the function to be reactive, and be triggered on every update of the slider. Not sure why that was not enough, but when I added another instance of `input$ord` to the front of the function it worked.

4- I also put a counter in the title of the `output$ma1` to help me debug the above-debugged lack of reactivity.

5 - I also combined both the shiny `ui.R` and `server.R` files into one file as this example is small and makes it easy to see everything at once. Note that it can be hard matching `ui.R` and `server.R` code with the Rstudio tabbed editor - it is worth getting another editor (like Atom or Notepad++) to help code if you need more than one file.

Comment: Maybe add some explanations too, so future readers won't need to play "find the difference".

Comment: Good point, although I didn't get his errors. But I can do some more.

Comment: Shiny has terrible error messages. I have been very frustrated with it on occasion. But there is no real competition.

Comment: I just wanna ask 2 questions additionally. First, when I change the input, the data is changed. In order to solve that should i use -for instance- "set.seed(123)"?
2. when play with k, the start point of red line should be changed either. For example, If i set the k 8, it should be begin 8th day, if it is 20 should be 20. Because it is a characteristic of moving average, isnt it?

Comment: To 1, yes, you can set the seed explicitly so that it always generates the same random number sequence, but maybe just generating the `tmp` array outside (before) the `output$ma1 = renderPlot(` code so that it is not regenerated every time would be better and more what you want.

Comment: As for 2, I would then the `SMA` function would take care of that detail for you, but I would have to check. Does it look wrong?

Comment: To me, it looks wrong. Eventhough i change k, the starting point of red line does not change.